# Xpath cannot be copied in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am currently trying to automate the export of a report from LinkedIn SalesNavigator but I am stuck to a filter where the default selection is 30 days but I want to select 7 days as per the below screenshot:
[Salesnav -export filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CShym.png) .

I've been using also Selectorshub to find the xpath since its a hidden element and I get the below message "*This element interchangeable through selenium as it is not visible in UI. Try a nearby element*"

Is there something I can do??

Comment: Can you add the `HTML` source for the element you trying to locate ?

Comment: <button aria-expanded="false" data-control-name="date_filter" id="ember685" class="flex align-items-center artdeco-dropdown__trigger--non-button p0 artdeco-dropdown__trigger artdeco-dropdown__trigger--placement-bottom ember-view" type="button" tabindex="0">
      <div class="inline">
        <span class="t-14 t-black--light">Date range:</span>
        <span class="t-14 t-bold">
            Last 7 days
        </span>
      </div>

Comment: Have you tried the xpath `//*[contains(text(),'Last 7 days')]`? Sometimes the button is hidden underneath the displayed element, so simply clicking on the words themself will lead to the action you are hoping for.

Comment: @Josh Heaps unfortunately it didn't work.  I tried like this = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Last 7 days')]") AND WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Last 7 days')]")))

Comment: Check if there a parent element that contains the word "shadow root"

Comment: Hey Luke! Not really sure on how to do that!